# How to replace text on python shell

Tags: python

I would like to make a program that will print out number values. I want it to display the number, then replace it with another number. A little like this:

```
val = 0
for looper in range(1, 10):
   val += 1
   print (val)
   #Code to replace old number to new number
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you give an example of output? It's unclear what you're asking. What is wrong with the code you offered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want in-place update of the number, you can use \r.

```
import sys

val = 0
for looper in range(1, 10):
    val += 1
    sys.stdout.write("\r%d" % (val))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1) # sleep added so that you can see the effect
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for something to replace output in `sys.stdout`.

This is limited without using external libraries but you can do something like this:

```
import sys
import time

for number in xrange(10):
    # put number in 'stdout'
    sys.stdout.write(str(number))
    # empty stdout (by default it waits for a new line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    # display the number for some time
    time.sleep(1)
    # go back to beginning of input to override existing output
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are taking about carriage return 
use "\r" this with time.sleep(ms)

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3,  [@Teemu Kurppa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28781970/4279) could be written as:

```
import time

for i in range(1, 11):
    print(i, end='\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```